# How to solve the SVD problem with the constraint that the subspaces spanned the first K left and right vectors are the same?

Tags: matrix, optimization, constraints, svd

I'm trying to solve the problem of finding the K leading 'singular vectors' of a matrix. Different from the standard SVD problem, I need the subspace spanned by the left and right 'singular vectors' to be the same. The objective function  I consider is

my objective function

[image: my objective function]

which is equivalent to

equivalent objective function

[image: equivalent objective function]

Here M is a matrix with real valued entries that is not necessarily symmetric. K is smaller than n and $\| \|_*$ is representing the nuclear norm.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you for let me notice math.stackexchange.com :). I just put this question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3276214/how-to-solve-truncated-svd-problem-with-the-constraint-that-the-left-and-right-s.